# very poor performance from MySQL INNODB

Tags: mysql

lately my mysql 5.5.27 has been performing very poorly. I have changed just about everything in the config to try and see if it makes a difference with no luck. I am getting tables locked up constantly reaching 6-9 locks per table. My select queries take forever 300sec-1200sec.

**Moved Everything to PasteBin because it exceeded 30k chars**
http://pastebin.com/bP7jMd97

**SYS ACTIVITIES**

90% `UPDATES` AND `INSERTS`
10% `SELECT`

My slow query log is backed up. below I have my mysql info. Please let me know if there is anything i should add that would help.

```
Server version          5.5.27-log
Protocol version        10
Connection              XX.xx.xxx via TCP/IP
TCP port                3306
Uptime:                 21 hours 39 min 40 sec



Uptime: 78246  Threads: 125  Questions: 6764445  Slow queries: 25  Opens: 1382  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 22  Queries per second avg: 86.451
```

**SHOW OPEN TABLES**

```
+----------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table         | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| aridb   | ek            |      0 |           0 |
| aridb   | ey            |      0 |           0 |
| aridb   | ts            |      4 |           0 |
| aridb   | tts           |      6 |           0 |
| aridb   | tg            |      0 |           0 |
| aridb   | tgle          |      2 |           0 |
| aridb   | ts            |      5 |           0 |
| aridb   | tg2           |      1 |           0 |
| aridb   | bts           |      0 |           0 |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+
```

I've hit a brick wall and need some guidance. thanks!

Comment: are specific statements causing issues, or starting them off? - Also do you use many views over the same underlying data?

Comment: i haven't noticed any specific statements, it tends to be random. I tried to monitor what time of the day it occurs, but it is very random. I dont have any `views` for any of my data. there are inserts and updates running 24/7 none stop. I run select's to see the data returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking through your log it would seem the problem (as I’m quite sure you’re aware) is due to the huge amount of locks that are present given the amount of data being updated / selected / inserted and possible at the same time.

It is really hard to give performance tips without first knowing lots of information which you don’t provide such as size of tables, schema, hardware, config, topology etc – SO probably isn’t the best place for such a broad question anyway!

I’ll keep my answer as generic as I can, but possible things to look at or try would be:

1. Run [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) the select queries and make sure they are selectively finding data and not performing full table scans or wasting huge amounts of data
2. Leave the server to do it's inserts and updates but create a [read replica](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html) for reporting, this way data won’t be locked
3. If you’re updating many rows at a time, think about [updating with a limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) supplied to stop so much data being locked
4. If you are able to, [delay the inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) to relieve pressure
5. Look at a hardware fix such as Solid State Disks for IO performance and more memory so more indexing / data can be held in memory or to have a larger buffer